# After importing products into Magento, the categories aren't being checked

Tags: import, category

No products show up because the category isn't selected

[image: This is what the backend looks like under Categories]

I have removed all the extra nonsense and just added what I needed to.

Here is my csv file.  I have just been adding anything to the end to make this work.

```
sku,category,name,store,visibility,status,_attribute_set,attribute_set,_type,_root_category,websites,_product,type,qty,is_in_stock,product_type_id
56600,"Kayak / Paddle Sports",Bulk Stick On Fish Tape Measure,admin,"Catalog, Search",Enabled,Default,Default,simple,Catalog,base,base,simple,100,1,simple
```

I can check the category after uploading, but when uploading 100 or so products, this isn't going to be an option.  How do I ensure the category is selected?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating one product perfectly within magento admin (manually). Save this product. 
Then export the product CSV from magento. This will give you all the correct column headings and you can then populate additional rows with your new products and then reimport. I hope this helps.
edit: when making a perfect product in magento, make sure you add it to the category that you are having trouble with via magento backend. Then when you export the product csv look at that product to see what category id has been assigned to it.

Comment: Correct column headings, plus depending on version, the category column uses the actual category IDs in a comma separated list.

Comment: Do you have multiple storeviews? eg, USA, Canada? If so this may be a consideration. If not, never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try `_category` instead of `category`.

Comment: Didn't change anything with this.  Thanks for attempt.
Edit:  Should I be using the ID's for the categories? This may not be great when adding new categories, or for the people putting these together, but I don't understand what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of the slash '/' character in your category name which magento assumes as paddle sports is a subcategory of kayak which is not in your case. Try with a category name not containing slash character, and your product should be added to that category quite well.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the profile import/export, Magento uses a comma separated list of category IDs in the **category** column. If you want to import categoryies, you will have to determine each category and sub category ID in the path and add them into that column as below.

```
"store","websites","attribute_set","type","category_ids","sku","has_options","name","meta_title"
"admin","base","Default","simple","2737,2807,2808","test-product","1","test-product","test-product","test-product"
```

Answer (score 0):

For categories having slash in their name you must HTML encode the slash like `&#47;`.

I read this from [this article](https://www.onetakemedia.net/magento/dealing-with-slashes-in-magento-category-names/)